# Retrieve information from a configmap using jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath, configmap

I have the following `configmap` where I want to retrieve the IPs using jsonpath how can that be done?

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  domain.yaml: |
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 127.0.0.2
```

I have tried the following which does not work: `kubectl get cm domain -o jsonpath={.domain.yaml.dns[0]}`

Comment: It's a string  `"domain.yaml": "dns: \n  - 127.0.0.1\n  - 127.0.0.1\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not quite simple, as the

```
dns:
- 127.0.0.1
- 127.0.0.2
```

is interpreted as a single json value.

for example `kubectl get cm testcm -o jsonpath='{.data}'` returns the following output `{"domain.yaml":"dns:\n  - 127.0.0.1\n  - 127.0.0.2\n"}`
as you can see it has "domain.yaml" as key, and the rest is a simple string value.

in order to get the ips, we can use jq and cut magic. For example

```
kubectl get cm testcm -o jsonpath='{.data.*}' | cut -d$'\n' -f2 | sed 's/  - //g'
```

would return `127.0.0.1`